# What is the right command-line to deal with switching pages in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, function

I'm working on a class project, and I've created an app where you can navigate to the next page by clicking on an icon, similar to how apps work. When I click the home icon twice, it takes me to page 2 which shouldnt happen.I want it to where when you click on home icon it goes to the home and whenyou click on the search is goes to the search like a app but when i click on the icons 2 times it shows another page. I'll be adding a video so you can see it in action along with sharing my code. I'm new to all of this and could use some help. If anyone is willing to direct message me and offer assistance, that would be greatly appreciated. I might have some questions along the way. Thanks!

here is the html

```
<!-- Icons at the bottom for navigation -->
<div class="bottom-container">
    <div class="bottom-icons">
        <div class="icon" onclick="showHomePage()">
            <img src="images/homepagepng.png" alt="Home Icon" class="icon1-img" />
        </div>
        <div class="icon" onclick="showSearchPage()">
            <img src="images/searchpng.png" alt="Search Icon" class="icon1-img" />
        </div>
        <div class="icon" onclick="showPostPage()">
            <img src="images/post.png" alt="Post Icon" class="icon1-img" />
        </div>
        <div class="icon" onclick="showNotificationsPage()">
            <img src="images/notificationpng.png" alt="Notifications Icon" class="icon1-img" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 
<!-- Search Page -->
<div class="app" id="search-content" style="display: none;">
    <div class="app-wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="subtitle">Search your favorite creators</div>p
            <div class="bottom-container">
                <div class="bottom-icons">
                    <div class="icon" onclick="showHomePage()">
                        <img src="images/homepagepng.png" alt="Home Icon" class="icon1-img" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon" onclick="showSearchPage()">
                        <img src="images/searchpng.png" alt="Search Icon" class="icon1-img" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon" onclick="showPostPage()">
                        <img src="images/post.png" alt="Post Icon" class="icon1-img" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon" onclick="showNotificationsPage()">
                        <img src="images/notificationpng.png" alt="Notifications Icon" class="icon1-img" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 
<!-- Post Page -->
<div class="app" id="post-content" style="display: none;">
    <div class="app-wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="subtitle">Posting Page</div>
            <div class="bottom-container">
                <div class="bottom-icons">
                    <div class="icon" onclick="showHomePage()">
                        <img src="images/homepagepng.png" alt="Home Icon" class="icon1-img" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon" onclick="showSearchPage()">
                        <img src="images/searchpng.png" alt="Search Icon" class="icon1-img" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon" onclick="showPostPage()">
                        <img src="images/post.png" alt="Post Icon" class="icon1-img" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon" onclick="showNotificationsPage()">
                        <img src="images/notificationpng.png" alt="Notifications Icon" class="icon1-img" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 
<!-- Notifications Page -->
<div class="app" id="notifications-content" style="display: none;">
    <div class="app-wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="subtitle">Notifications Page</div>
            <div class="bottom-container">
                <div class="bottom-icons">
                    <div class="icon" onclick="showHomePage()">
                        <img src="images/homepagepng.png" alt="Home Icon" class="icon1-img" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon" onclick="showSearchPage()">
                        <img src="images/searchpng.png" alt="Search Icon" class="icon1-img" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon" onclick="showPostPage()">
                        <img src="images/post.png" alt="Post Icon" class="icon1-img" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon" onclick="showNotificationsPage()">
                        <img src="images/notificationpng.png" alt="Notifications Icon" class="icon1-img" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the Js

```
<script>
    var currentPageId = '';
    
    function switchPage(pageId) {
    if (currentPageId !== pageId) {
    var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('app');
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    pages[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    
    var selectedPage = document.getElementById(pageId);
    if(statment) {
    selectedPage.style.display = 'flex';
    currentPageId = pageId;
    }
    }
    }
    
    function showHomePage() {
    switchPage('home-content');
    }
    
    function showSearchPage() {
    switchPage('search-content');
    }
    
    function showPostPage() {
    switchPage('post-content');
    }
    
    function showNotificationsPage() {
    switchPage('notifications-content');
    }
    
    function submitPost() {
    alert("Post submitted!");
    showHomePage();
    }
    </script>
```

Now this is the javascript code that i think is messing it up

hopefully someone can find why its doing this
also i tried putting if(statement) also still did the same thing
also here a video https://streamable.com/xx5fd9

also i tried putting if(statement) also still did the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve the issue?

```js
var currentPageId = 'home-content';

function switchPage(pageId) {
  if (currentPageId !== pageId) {
    var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('app');
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
      pages[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    var selectedPage = document.getElementById(pageId);
    if (selectedPage) {
      selectedPage.style.display = 'flex';
      currentPageId = pageId;
    }
  }
}

function showHomePage() {
  switchPage('home-content');
}

function showSearchPage() {
  switchPage('search-content');
}

function showPostPage() {
  switchPage('post-content');
}

function showNotificationsPage() {
  switchPage('notifications-content');
}

function submitPost() {
  alert("Post submitted!");
  showHomePage();
}
```

```html
<!-- Home Page -->
<div class="app" id="home-content">
  <div class="app-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="subtitle">Home page</div>
      <div class="bottom-container">
        <div class="bottom-icons">
          <div class="icon" onclick="showHomePage()">
            <img src="images/homepagepng.png" alt="Home Icon" class="icon1-img" />
          </div>
          <div class="icon" onclick="showSearchPage()">
            <img src="images/searchpng.png" alt="Search Icon" class="icon1-img" />
          </div>
          <div class="icon" onclick="showPostPage()">
            <img src="images/post.png" alt="Post Icon" class="icon1-img" />
          </div>
          <div class="icon" onclick="showNotificationsPage()">
            <img src="images/notificationpng.png" alt="Notifications Icon" class="icon1-img" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Search Page -->
<div class="app" id="search-content" style="display: none;">
  <div class="app-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="subtitle">Search your favorite creators</div>
      <div class="bottom-container">
        <div class="bottom-icons">
          <div class="icon" onclick="showHomePage()">
            <img src="images/homepagepng.png" alt="Home Icon" class="icon1-img" />
          </div>
          <div class="icon" onclick="showSearchPage()">
            <img src="images/searchpng.png" alt="Search Icon" class="icon1-img" />
          </div>
          <div class="icon" onclick="showPostPage()">
            <img src="images/post.png" alt="Post Icon" class="icon1-img" />
          </div>
          <div class="icon" onclick="showNotificationsPage()">
            <img src="images/notificationpng.png" alt="Notifications Icon" class="icon1-img" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Post Page -->
<div class="app" id="post-content" style="display: none;">
  <div class="app-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="subtitle">Posting Page</div>
      <div class="bottom-container">
        <div class="bottom-icons">
          <div class="icon" onclick="showHomePage()">
            <img src="images/homepagepng.png" alt="Home Icon" class="icon1-img" />
          </div>
          <div class="icon" onclick="showSearchPage()">
            <img src="images/searchpng.png" alt="Search Icon" class="icon1-img" />
          </div>
          <div class="icon" onclick="showPostPage()">
            <img src="images/post.png" alt="Post Icon" class="icon1-img" />
          </div>
          <div class="icon" onclick="showNotificationsPage()">
            <img src="images/notificationpng.png" alt="Notifications Icon" class="icon1-img" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Notifications Page -->
<div class="app" id="notifications-content" style="display: none;">
  <div class="app-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="subtitle">Notifications Page</div>
      <div class="bottom-container">
        <div class="bottom-icons">
          <div class="icon" onclick="showHomePage()">
            <img src="images/homepagepng.png" alt="Home Icon" class="icon1-img" />
          </div>
          <div class="icon" onclick="showSearchPage()">
            <img src="images/searchpng.png" alt="Search Icon" class="icon1-img" />
          </div>
          <div class="icon" onclick="showPostPage()">
            <img src="images/post.png" alt="Post Icon" class="icon1-img" />
          </div>
          <div class="icon" onclick="showNotificationsPage()">
            <img src="images/notificationpng.png" alt="Notifications Icon" class="icon1-img" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @sql Let me know if there's something else that you wanted to achieve. Besides that, there is a lot of redundant code here which you could clean up. Let me know it you wish to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To simply redirect a browser using javascript:

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com/new_url";
```

To redirect AND submit a form (i.e. login details), requires no javascript:

```
<form action="/new_url" method="POST">
   <input name="username">
   <input type="password" name="password">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Or You can use

`window.open(stringURL);`
to open the html in a new window.

To open a new tab:

`window.open(stringURL, “_blank”);`

Comment: hey but im trying to keep all my code on one file instead of having another htlm file

Comment: @sql, Why did you write "statement" in `var selectedPage = document.getElementById(pageId);
    if(statment) {` ? 
Please fix like
`if (selectedPage) {
    selectedPage.style.display = 'block';
    currentPageId = pageId;
}`

Comment: again im new to all of this ngl also when i was aksing someone they told me to write statement

Comment: if you know how to fix whats going on can you pls help i have a deadline on this in 2 days

Comment: `statement` is not defined in this context. If someone said like that, then it means target element statement. I mean you can fix like `var statement = document.getElementById(pageId);
    if(statment) {
    selectedPage.style.display = 'flex';
    currentPageId = pageId;
    }`

Comment: Hey its still doing it   here a video https://streamable.com/xhd22s

Comment: Sorry,  try `        var statement = document.getElementById(pageId);
        if (statement) {
            statement.style.display = 'block';
            currentPageId = pageId;
        }`

Comment: still doing it  for some reason i'll show another vid also i'll show you hot my html file is setup https://streamable.com/rze2ij

Comment: how* also wanna ty for helping